# Как на javascript передать переменные в тело POST запроса (fetch)?

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

Есть файл с html-разметкой. К нему подключен файл js.

Нужно сделать POST-запрос с помощью fetch. Хочу использовать в теле запроса переменную.

Получаю значения переменной из клика по элементу списка.
В html-файле:

При нажатии на элемент списка вызывается функция getType:

```
<li onclick="getType(event)" v-for="i in types"> {{ i }} </li>
```

(types - просто массив)

Кнопка, по нажатию которой должен происходить запрос (также находится в html-файле):

```
             <div id="button">
                <button class="btn btn-success" 
                onclick="
                sendCalcRequestF('POST', requestCalcURL, body)
                .then(data => console.log(data))
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
                "
                ondblclick="echo()">
                рассчитать
            </button>
            </div>
```

Код в js-файле:

```
let chooseType;

function getType(event) {
    chooseType = event.target.innerHTML;
    console.log(chooseType);
    return chooseType;
}

const body = {
    type: chooseType,
 }

const headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

function sendCalcRequestF(method, url, body) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
}

function echo() {
     console.log("body", body)
}
```

Полученные с помощью getType данные нормально выводятся в консоль, но тело запроса в итоге остаётся пустым (это видно при выводе его в консоль, и запрос не работает)

Тело при выводе в консоль выглядит так (вывожу с помощью функции echo(), описанной в js-файле и вызываемой при двойном клике на кнопку):

```
{type: undefined}
```

Причём тот же самый код совершенно нормально работает с другим body, где значение задано изначально:

```
const body2 = {
    type: "шрот"
}
```

(остальной код не меняю, просто вместо body передаю в функцию в качестве параметра body2, и всё работает)

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите весь ваш код в примере. не очень понятно где вы присваиваете body?

Comment: @Meth0d вопрос отредактирован, body создаю в js-файле

Comment: где ты выводишь body в консоль?

Comment: @Grundy  в функции echo, описываю её в js, вызываю в html при двойном нажатии на кнопку (ondlclick).

Comment: в функции echo выводится body, но ты его нигде не заполняешь

Comment: @Grundy А здесь я разве не заполняю body?
`const body = { type: chooseType, }`
То есть мне нужно сделать что-то ещё, кроме этого, чтобы его заполнить?

Comment: В момент когда ты это делаешь `chooseType` равен `undefined`, дальше ты объект нигде не меняешь, поэтому и получаешь `{type: undefined}`

Comment: @esa, к сожалению уже не могу дать ответ. вам нужно инициализировать переменную `const body = {}` в начале, а не `chooseType` и в функции `getType` заполнять `body.type = event.target.innerHTML`. В таком случае все работать будет. До этого заполнение body происходило при рендере страницы, поэтому там и `undefined`, теперь же заполнение происходит по событию - именно то что вам нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужно инициализировать переменную `const body = {}` в начале, а не `chooseType` и в функции `getType` заполнять `body.type = event.target.innerHTML`. В таком случае все работать будет. До этого заполнение `body` происходило при рендере страницы, поэтому там и `undefined`, теперь же заполнение происходит по событию - именно то что вам нужно